# Let $o_p(a) = 3$, show that $o_p(1+a) = 6$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The question is : let $o_p(a) = 3$. Show that $o_p(1+a) = 6.$

I'm not sure of how to solve this question and would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should start by defining $o_p$.

Comment: Perhaps order...

Comment: I apologize! I believe it's defined as order, in the following way: $o_n = k>0$ if $a^m$ is congruent to $ 1 (mod n)$.

Comment: And what do you know about $p$?

Comment: @Mathmaniac You are asking us to help you and you don't know what are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume $p$ is prime.

Since $ord_p(a)=3$ we have $p\mid a^3 -1 = (a-1)(a^2+a+1)$. Since
$ord_p(a) >1$ we have $p\nmid a-1$ and thus $p\mid a^2+a+1$. Now $$(a+1)^6-1 \equiv_p21(a^2+a+1)\equiv_p 0$$ so $ord_p(1+a) \mid 6$. Now show $ord_p(1+a) >3$...